# SqlDataReader performance

Tags: .net, sql-server, sqldatareader

I have a performance issue with SqlDataReader. It seems that the bottleneck is reading large string rows (some values are about 2Kb). It takes 20 minutes to read 5000 rows whereas the same query executes in SSMS in less than 20 seconds and returns the same data. Is there any way to speed up SqlDataReader?

**UPDATE**

It doesn't look like execution plan issue because .Net profiler shows that `GetValue` method (and internally `TryReadSqlStringValue`) consumes all the time.

**UPDATE 2**

Yes, it was an issue with different executions plans even though queries were the same. After `sp_updatestats` call performance was fixed.

Comment: Check this post - http://www.somewheresomehow.ru/fast-in-ssms-slow-in-app-part1/

Comment: This article mostly relates to executions plans but the profiler shows that most of time is consumed by reading string fields

Comment: Profiler of what? BTW read about `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` if you have parameters in your query

Comment: Profiler of .Net code. As I understand if the reason is slow execution plan the profiler would show more time for `Read()` method rather than `GetValue()`

Comment: You understood correctly. Please provide actual execution plan

Comment: How would it help if you confirmed that it's not the reason?

Comment: If you think that problem in `SqlDataReader`... i will not oppose of your opinion. Thanks.

Comment: I just asked you to explain why do you agree about performance of methods `Read` and `GetValue` but still ask about execution plan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSMS also uses SqlDataReader.  The performance issue due may be due to either a different query execution plan or app code in processing the results.  Start by comparing the plans.  Below is an example to get the plan(s) from cache.

```
SELECT sql_text.text, query_plan.query_plan
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans AS cached_plans
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(plan_handle) AS sql_text
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(plan_handle) AS query_plan
WHERE sql_text.text LIKE N'%Your query%';
```